# jQuery(".element").scrollTop(0); doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have multiple tabs like this:

> [tab 1] [tab 2]
>
> --content
>
> [tab 1] [tab 2]

**HTML:**

```
<div class="tabs">

    <ul class="tab-links">
        <li class="active"><a href="#tab1">Tab #1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab2">Tab #2</a></li>
    </ul>  

    <div class="tab-content">

        <div id="tab1" class="tab active">#1 content</div>

        <div id="tab2" class="tab">#2 content </div> 

    </div>

    <div class="tabs">

        <ul class="tab-links">
            <li class="active"><a href="#tab1">Tab #1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tab2">Tab #2</a></li>
        </ul>

    </div>

</div>
```

As you can see there are tab list above and below the tab-content.

As long as content is long, user has to scroll-up to page when he change the tab on the tab-list-bottom.

So, I wanted to scrollTop automatically when user change the tab from below. And I added `jQuery(".tab-content").scrollTop(0);` into the java-script code. But somehow It doesn't respond.

**jsFiddle:**

http://jsfiddle.net/4m2ut16k/8/

**Note:** It works when I change `jQuery(".tab-content").scrollTop(0);` to `jQuery(window).scrollTop(0);` but this is not what I want because my content not on the top of page.

Just can't understand why it doesn't work on the first place. Has anyone figure out what is the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to scroll the window to the top of the tabs container, you can get the offset of the `.tab-content` element by using jquery offset function and then get the top attribute:

```
jQuery(window).scrollTop(jQuery(".tab-content").offset().top);
```

Comment: No problem. Glad to help.